# Error using array function in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

This sounds very simple but I have been struggling with it!

In AngularJs 1.4, I have an ng-if which is using array's some() function. I get syntax error

> Syntax Error: Token '>' not a primary expression at column ...

when doing this.

My HTML is:

```
<!-- DOES NOT WORK!! -->
<div ng-if="myArr.some(x => x == 'car')">
  Function check fine!
</div>
```

Here is the plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/v5SLIU5dQdIlpP5sCmzR

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular uses its own built-in parser to evaluate the expressions in your templates, which [does not support function declarations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). You should pull the logic out of your template and into the controller, and then bind to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe for the quick answer. I have to wait 5 more mins before I can accept it!

Comment: @Vikram: Glad I could help :) I think this slips most people up at some point while they're working with Angular 1.x.